# Web audio API: scheduling sounds and exporting the mix

Tags: audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I've been checking Web Audio API documentation and the tutorials but haven't quiet figured out how to approach this problem.

Let's say I load few wav files via XMLHttpRequest and then create buffersources. I know I can schedule when the playback starts precisely. But what if I don't want to play them, but instead want to store and schedule them in a buffer.

A real example: I want to create a simple sequencer where you schedule drums and than export the whole mix to wav (without recording it using RecorderJS or something). Any ideas, libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just did something a bit like this.

Essentially, you'll need to create an offline context:

```
var offline = new webkitOfflineAudioContext(numChannels, lengthInSamples, sampleRate)
```

You'll have to recreate all your BufferSources using this new context:

```
var newBufferSource = offline.createBufferSource();
newBufferSource.buffer = someAudioBuffer;
newBufferSource.connect(offline.destination);
```

Then schedule your playback:

```
newBufferSource.start(offline.currentTime + 10);
```

Then bind to the `complete` event for your offline rendering:

```
offline.onComplete = function( ev ){
  doSomething(ev.renderedBuffer);
}
```

Then start 'rendering':

```
offline.startRendering();
```

Once you have `ev.renderedBuffer`, you can do whatever you want with it. In my app, I have a WAV encoder that I ended up writing myself - but you could modify Recorder.js to do the same thing pretty easily.

Just a heads-up: `webkitOfflineAudioContext` is Chrome-only at the moment. Here's a link if you're interested: [OfflineAudioContext](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#OfflineAudioContext)

Comment: Somehow I didn't figure out the purpose of this offline context just by looking at the documentation. Thank you so much :) Here is a working example I've made: http://jsfiddle.net/jC6rd/

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got up and running.

Comment: offline.startRendering();  not working in safari , any solution for this ?