# How do I compress multiple Web Audio sources/tracks into one?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, html5-audio, web-audio-api

We are making an web based music editor and mixer based on the Web Audio api. Users can mix together multiple tracks, crop tracks, etc.  The actual mixing together of the tracks just involves playing back all the sources at once.

We want to be able to add the option to save the mix and make it available for download to a user's computer.  Is there some way to do this on the front end (like connecting all the sources to one destination/export node), or even the backend (we are using RoR)?

Comment: It's certainly doable on the back end, but you need to send your mix data and all audio files to the server if the aren't there alredy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RecorderJS does exactly what you need, and it could not possibly be easier to use. Really, really great library.

https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs

P.S. Look into `OfflineAudioContext` and my answer to this question ([Web audio API: scheduling sounds and exporting the mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969201/web-audio-api-scheduling-sounds-and-exporting-the-mix)) for info on doing a faster-than-realtime mixdown of your audio.

Comment: Awesome, this looks like exactly what we need, and it doesn't seem like we have to modify very much of our existing code.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Users data looks to be on client side?

Basically when converting data with base64 into dataURI, datas are diplayed inline so they can be add 1 by 1 togheter into one single blob object, and be downloaded.

But this method is only good for smalls files, causing crash and freezing with most browser, this is only good for blob size less than 10mb after some personnal tests, this will be better soon for sure.

```
<audio controls><source src="data:audio/ogg;base64,BASE64.......BASE564......BASE64............."></audio>
```

or

```
<a href="data:audio/ogg;base64,BASE64...BASE64..BASE64....>Download</a>
```

Probably not your way, just an idea but your project is interesting ;)

Comment: What about livestreaming ? Can i add the datas 1 by 1 in a stream?