# Hi I need to build a web site to mix two audio file and export only one, how can I do it?

Tags: javascript, audio, web, html5-audio

The only thing I need is mix the audio files, I need to manage the volume of those files and finaly export an audio file .wav

I was searching in the internet but don't find nothing. Could I use javascript o some plugin to do it?

Thanks and I hope you can help me.

Comment: what you mean by mix? Add one after the other? You could prbably handle this better by server

Comment: no, i mean get a new audio file that sounds like the other two was playing at the same time.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22135056/overlay-two-audio-buffers-into-one-buffer-source or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016656/html5-javascript-audio-play-multiple-tracks-at-the-same-time

Comment: these won't work since he want to export as wave and not play them

Comment: Well, in that case it needs to be handled by server

Comment: Do you know how to do it by server?

Comment: look at my aswer "I suggest asp.net mvc or ruby on rails for this project." there are many books covering these subjects

Comment: and to anyone down voting his question, we have someone interested in learning web development here with a cool project in mind. He simply need guidance to get started. Stack Overflow is a place to help others, not tell them that their question is stupid.

Comment: This might work for client side but seems it only works in chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159387/how-do-i-compress-multiple-web-audio-sources-tracks-into-one

Comment: Thank you so much for help me @AntoineLev. I hope solve this early.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upload both the file to the server and then run some digital signal processing algorithms to mix the two signals. Once done, return a link to the file.

Here are some books on dsp for audio : 
http://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=digital%20signal%20processing%20audio

I suggest asp.net mvc or ruby on rails for this project.