# MIX Wav file and export it with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I'm a web developer from japan.
This is first question on stack over flow.

I'm creating a simple music Web application now.
making a music system program is a completely beginner, so I am struggling to implement it.

As a result of various investigations, I noticed that using the Web Audio API was the best choice,
so, I decided to use it.

## ▼ What I want to achieve

- `Multiple Wav files` load with the Web audio API can be grouped into `one Wav file` &To be able to download from the browser.

For example, load the multiple wav file like guitar, drum and piano, and 
edit it on the browser, and finally output it as one Wav file.
Then we can download that edited wav file from the browser and we are able to play itunes.

### ▼ Question

- Is it possible to achieve this requirements by just using web audio api ?
- or we need to use another Library ?

I checked Record.js on github but development has stopped about 2 ~ 3 years and has many issues and  I can not get support. so I decided not to use it.
and also I checked similar issue [Web audio API: scheduling sounds and exporting the mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969201/web-audio-api-scheduling-sounds-and-exporting-the-mix)

Since the information is old, I do not know if I can still use it 
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow!

## Is it possible to achieve this just using the web audio api?

In terms of merging/mixing the files together this is perfectly achievable! [This article](https://medium.com/creative-technology-concepts-code/recording-syncing-and-exporting-web-audio-1e1a1e35ef08) goes through many (if not all) of the steps you will need to carry out the task you suggested.

Each file you want to upload can be loaded into an [AudioBufferSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode) (examples explained in [that article linked before](https://medium.com/creative-technology-concepts-code/recording-syncing-and-exporting-web-audio-1e1a1e35ef08)) Example setting up a buffer source once the audio data has been loaded in:

```
play: function (data, callback) {
    // create audio node and play buffer
    var me = this,
        source = this.context.createBufferSource(),
        gainNode = this.context.createGain();
    if (!source.start) { source.start = source.noteOn; }
    if (!source.stop) { source.stop = source.noteOff; }
    source.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(this.context.destination);
    source.buffer = data;
    source.loop = true;
    source.startTime = this.context.currentTime; // important for later!
    source.start(0);
    return source;
}
```

There are then also specific nodes already designed for your mixing purposes like the [ChannelMergerNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelMergerNode) (combines multiple mono channels into a new channel buffer). This is if you don't want to deal with the signal processing yourself in javascript but will be faster using the Web Audio objects since they are native compiled code already within the browser.

Following that [complete guide sent before](https://medium.com/creative-technology-concepts-code/recording-syncing-and-exporting-web-audio-1e1a1e35ef08), there are also options to export the file (as a .wav in the demo case) using the following code :

```
var rate = 22050;

function exportWAV(type, before, after){
    if (!before) { before = 0; }
    if (!after) { after = 0; }

    var channel = 0,
        buffers = [];
    for (channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel++){
        buffers.push(mergeBuffers(recBuffers[channel], recLength));
    }

    var i = 0,
        offset = 0,
        newbuffers = [];

    for (channel = 0; channel < numChannels; channel += 1) {
        offset = 0;
        newbuffers[channel] = new Float32Array(before + recLength + after);
        if (before > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < before; i += 1) {
                newbuffers[channel].set([0], offset);
                offset += 1;
            }
        }
        newbuffers[channel].set(buffers[channel], offset);
        offset += buffers[channel].length;
        if (after > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < after; i += 1) {
                newbuffers[channel].set([0], offset);
                offset += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (numChannels === 2){
        var interleaved = interleave(newbuffers[0], newbuffers[1]);
    } else {
        var interleaved = newbuffers[0];
    }

    var downsampledBuffer = downsampleBuffer(interleaved, rate);
    var dataview = encodeWAV(downsampledBuffer, rate);
    var audioBlob = new Blob([dataview], { type: type });

    this.postMessage(audioBlob);
}
```

So I think Web-Audio has everything you could want for this purpose! However could be challenging depending on your web development experience, but its a skill definately worth learning!

## Do we need to use another library?

If you can I think it's definately worth trying it with [Web-Audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), as you'll almost definately get the best speeds for processing, but there are other libraries such as [Pizzicato.js](https://alemangui.github.io/pizzicato/) just to name one. I'm sure you will find plenty others.

Comment: Awesome ! 
I will try my best by reading these guide and code !
There are lots of great developers in stack over flow !! ^^

Comment: No worries @Toshiki ! If my answer was right could you please mark it?